# How to sort/group notifications in iOS 10 Notification Center

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

In the Notification Center in iOS 9 it was possible to group notifications per app or by time/day.  In iOS 10 I don't find the setting to change this behaviour.  Do someone know if it can be changed or is this setting not available any more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry if it doesn't answer your question. This is the first thing that I noticed as soon as I installed the new iOS 10 on my iPhone 6. I had words with the Apple support and they told me that it is no longer possible to group notifications by app with the new iOS 10. I’ve also submitted the feedback to Apple regarding this issue here: http://www.apple.com/feedback

Comment: It seems you're right.  There is also discussion about that on an Apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7663611

Comment: This truly is unacceptable. iOS 10 destroyed a big part of my productivity/information workflow. Now, notifications are nearly useless as I never see anything in a timely fashion because I have to wait until I have time to sort through the muck. I also end up missing important things, and have had to give up and disable notifications for most apps just to keep it manageable. Does anyone know how Android handles notifications? I'm really starting to consider the switch.